# FileNotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, tensorflow, dump, pickle

При попытке повторного использования сохраненной модели нейронной сети получаю ошибку :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\VillCNN\1\run.py", line 23, in 
> model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
> File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\saving\pickle_utils.py", line 48, in deserialize_model_from_bytecode
> model = save_module.load_model(temp_dir)
> File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
> raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
> File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load.py", line 977, in load_internal
> raise FileNotFoundError(
> FileNotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for ram://16197d23-ea7a-44df-b95a-83b5ec02c2a9/variables/variables
> You may be trying to load on a different device from the computational device. Consider setting the `experimental_io_device` option in `tf.saved_model.LoadOptions` to the io_device such as '/job:localhost'.

Сохранение модели:

```
pickle.dump(label_binarizer,open('plant_disease_label_transform.pkl', 'wb'))
n_classes = len(label_binarizer.classes_)

#save the model to disk
# Dump pickle file of the model
print("[INFO] Сохранение модели...")
filename = 'plant_disease_classification_model.pkl'
pickle.dump(model, open(filename, 'wb'))
print("[INFO] Модель сохранена")
# Dump pickle file of the labels
print("[INFO] Сохранение меток...")
filename2 = 'plant_disease_label_transform.pkl'
image_labels = pickle.load(open(filename2, 'rb'))
print("[INFO] Модель сохранена")
```

Повторное использование:

```
# Load model
filename = r'D:\VillCNN\1\plant_disease_classification_model.pkl'
model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))

# Load labels
filename = r'D:\VillCNN\1\plant_disease_label_transform.pkl'
image_labels = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))

# Dimension of resized image
DEFAULT_IMAGE_SIZE = tuple((256, 256))

def convert_image_to_array(image_dir):
    try:
        image = cv2.imread(image_dir)
        if image is not None:
            image = cv2.resize(image, DEFAULT_IMAGE_SIZE)   
            return img_to_array(image)
        else:
            return np.array([])
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error : {e}")
        return None

def predict_disease(image_path):
    image_array = convert_image_to_array(image_path)
    np_image = np.array(image_array, dtype=np.float16) / 225.0
    np_image = np.expand_dims(np_image,0)
    plt.imshow(plt.imread(image_path))
    result = model.predict(np_image)
    print((image_labels.classes_[result][0]))
    
predict_disease(r'D:\PlantVillage\val\Corn_(maize)___Northern_Leaf_Blight\028159fc-995e-455a-8d60-6d377580a898___RS_NLB 4023.JPG')
```

Библиотеки:

```
import numpy as np
import pickle
import cv2
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from os import listdir
from sklearn.preprocessing  import LabelBinarizer
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Flatten, Dropout, Dense
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

Версия python 3.10, tenserflow 2.7, OC Windows. Путь к файлам прописан верный.

Comment: "You may be trying to load on a different device from the computational device" - ну оно пишет, что GPU другое (или настройки у него другие) при загрузке, а должно быть всё в точности такое же, как при сохранении модели.

Comment: @CrazyElf , это я понимаю. Но как исправить? Запускаю на одном устройстве. Как может, что-либо измениться ?

Comment: Почему вы не используете методы tensorflow / Keras для сохранения и загрузки модели?

Comment: @MaxU , не могу найти пример с повторным использованием модели. Знаю только как сохранить и загрузить модель.

Comment: Также заметил, что при использовании функции predict_disease, получаю ошибку:  _print((image_labels.classes_[result][0]))
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type_